# With RestSharp, Newtonsoft.Json Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, restsharp

I am new to C# API... I created a new server using nodejs server get data from SQL server to generate json and I am creating a custom application using c# windows application using RestSharp sent a request to a server and received a response using Newtonsoft I got error cannot deserialize current json array help me to solve the problem below code

JSON

```
[[{"id":2000,"engine":1,"wheel":1,"ac":1,"nitro":1,"rim":1},{"id":2001,"engine":1,"wheel":1,"ac":1,"nitro":1,"rim":1}]]
```

Code

```
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8000/employees");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
            foreach (var player in x.Abbrecipes)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(player.id);
            }
        }

public class Abbrecipe
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int engine { get; set; }
            public int wheel { get; set; }
            public int ac { get; set; }
            public int nitro { get; set; }
            public int rim { get; set; }
        }
        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Abbrecipe> Abbrecipes { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: did you see that your json has a `[]` too much?

Comment: Your JSON contains a collection of collections of objects, you need to deserialize to the same. Try `DeserializeObject<List<List<RootObject>>>(...)`

Comment: So its problem in server while converting json

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for your current situation as a method using `WebClient` instead of `RestClient`:

```
private static Rootobject publicFeed;

    public static void Set()
    {
        publicFeed = new Rootobject();

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string result;
            try
            {
                result = client.DownloadString("your json");//configure json stringdata
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This application needs a valid internet connection, please try again.");
                result = null;
                return;
            }

            publicFeed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result);
        }
    }
```